# How to execute another <h:form> using <f:ajax>?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I've noticed that this doesn't work for me and I'm wondering if it's just not possible:

```
<h:form id="one" prependid="false" >
  <h:commandButton>
    <f:ajax execute=":two">
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:form id="two" prependid="false">
  ... content ...
</h:form>
```

Whenever I click the button above ,I can see that the values on form `two` are not executed as expected.
Is this the normal JSF behavior?
To 'trick' it, I usually insert a hidden button in form `two` and trigger it using JavaScript code when the button in form `one` is clicked. But that's a 'trick' and makes me work extra when I'm not sure I have to.

I should mention the `render`ing another form is possible.

Could the `prependid` attribute be causing problems?

Thanks in Advance!

**UPDATE** Adding more information that might be relevant - adding the `prependid="false"` to the forms as it is used in the actual code.

Comment: First you could try `<f:ajax execute="@all"/>` to check if it is really a problem with ids (@all executes everything on the page). The missing slash in your ajax tag is a typo, isn't it?

Comment: @MattHandy See BalusC's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible with `<f:ajax>`. It just submits the parent form. The `execute` merely tells JSF which components it has to process based on the submitted data, not which request parameters the client side have to send. The button has really to go in the form where it belongs.

Comment: Okay.. That explains it.
Thank you!